# Passing Excel variables between Background Workers

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two background workers and need to pass things from the first one to the other.

**This is what I'm trying to pass:**

```
Dim APP As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim worksheetRange As Excel.Range
Dim status As String
```

**And this is how I'm trying to pass it:**

```
Private Sub bwExport_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwExport.DoWork
    Dim APP As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim worksheetRange As Excel.Range
    Dim status As String

    'code stuff here

    Dim ExportList As New List(Of Object)(5)
    ExportList.Add(APP)
    ExportList.Add(workbook)
    ExportList.Add(worksheet)
    ExportList.Add(worksheetRange)
    ExportList.Add(status)
    e.Result = ExportList
End Sub


Private Sub bwExport_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bwExport.RunWorkerCompleted
        bwExportFinish.RunWorkerAsync(e.Result)
End Sub
```

**And this is how I'm trying to retrieve it:**

```
Private Sub bwExportFinish_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwExportFinish.DoWork
    Dim ExportList As List(Of Object) = TryCast(e.Result, List(Of Object))
    Dim APP As Excel.Application = TryCast(ExportList(0), Excel.Application)
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook = TryCast(ExportList(1), Excel.Workbook)
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet = TryCast(ExportList(2), Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim worksheetRange As String = TryCast(ExportList(3), String)
    Dim status As String = TryCast(ExportList(4), String)

    'Save spreadsheet
    Dim SavePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\" & label1.Text & " " & Status & " Status " & System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy HH;mm;ss") & ".xlsx"
    workbook.SaveAs(SavePath)
    workbook.Close(False)
End Sub
```

**And this is the error that I'm getting:**
**1.** The line: *Dim APP As Excel.Application = TryCast(ExportList(0), Excel.Application())* 
gives me the error: *Value of type 'Application()' cannot be converted to 'Application'*.
**I'm blind. I just made a formatting error. This is fixed.**
**2.** I get an error that brings up a page in VS2015 that says "Source Not Available" and then *An unhandled exception of the type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `Passing Excel variables between Background Workers` This is potentially a lot of trouble; are you sure all the `Excel` types that you use are `thread safe`?

Comment: Well, the error actually explains it pretty well. Your original variable is of type `Excel.Application`, while `Excel.Application()` is an array of the same type. Hence, you would need to cast it as `Excel.Application` *if casting is even required*. Aside from that, I don't believe this is the correct approach as @Stefan pointed out. I think you should reconsider the need to pass the variables in the first place.

Comment: @Stefan No, I'm not unfortunately. I'm still learning coding and am unsure of thread safety. I did google it just now, but am unsure of what that would mean/entail as far as these Excel types go. If this isn't the way to go about passing these from one Background Worker to the other, would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you are sure only that one background-worker at a time access the excel object, then you're safe. If not we'll have to figure out an alternative.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks! That fixed that first problem, but I'm still having an issue with the TargetInvocationException error.

Comment: @Stefan Ah, yes I am sure that only one background-worker will have access at a time :).

Comment: Then all is good :-)

Comment: @lolikols, Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are a couple mistakes in your code, I'm going to point them out.

- As mentioned in my comment above:

  > The error actually explains it pretty well. Your original variable is
  >   of type Excel.Application, while Excel.Application() is an array of
  >   the same type. Hence, you would need to cast it as Excel.Application
  >   if casting is even required.
- In your second BackgroundWorker (`bwExportFinish`), you're trying to get the `List(Of Object)` which you passed from the first BackgroundWorker, but you're using the wrong variable (`e.Result`). How's that? Well, you store the list in `e.Result` of the *first* BackgroundWorker not the *second* one. Now after you pass that list to the second BackgroundWorker, you can access it using `e.Argument` not `e.Result`.
- Another minor mistake is that you created the variable `worksheetRange` of type `Excel.Range` and then you cast it as `String`.

Hence, your code in the second BackgroundWorker should look something like the following:

```
Private Sub bwExportFinish_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwExportFinish.DoWork
    Dim ExportList As List(Of Object) = TryCast(e.Argument, List(Of Object))
    If ExportList Is Nothing Then
        ' Casting has failed. Choose how you want to handle this.
    End If

    'Dim APP As Excel.Application = TryCast(ExportList(0), Excel.Application)
    'Or you can skip the casting if you already know you passed the right object.
    Dim APP As Excel.Application = ExportList(0)
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook = ExportList(1)
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet = ExportList(2)
    Dim worksheetRange As Excel.Range = ExportList(3)
    Dim status As String = ExportList(4)

    'Save spreadsheet
    workbook.SaveAs(SavePath)
    workbook.Close(False)
    APP.Quit()
End Sub
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hey, thanks! I made the appropriate changes, but I'm still getting an error that brings up a page in VS2015 that says "Source Not Available" and then An unhandled exception of the type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.

Comment: I guess in that case we might need to have a look on what other code you have under the first BackgroundWorker which might be altering the variables somehow. As for now, I made a quick test using your `bwExport_DoWork` code with some extra work made to the range, then triggered the modified `bwExportFinish_DoWork` code, and it worked just fine.

Comment: The first background worker is actually copying information from a different workbook to the one that I've declared in the code above. It's pretty lenghty code, but I can post it if you want. The code actually worked perfectly when I declared excel publicly, but I'm trying to declare it in the background worker which seems to make a muck of things.

Comment: It looks like e.Result threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'  when I first declare it e.Result = ExportList.

Comment: @lolikols, I would debug this by trying as minimal example as possible at first to try to locate my mistake. [This is my example](https://codepaste.net/jtf2cy) which works for me. You can test it and if it works, you can start from there by adding one step at a time. That should help you find were the problem is. If you're still stuck with it, you can post more info, and I'll try to help you :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry to keep bothering you about this. I tried for about 40 minutes now to get it working, and I couldn't. Here's my code if you want to have a look: https://codepaste.net/dpwkmh

Comment: Did you try the minimal example or not? If yes, did it work for you? If no, what exception did you get and where?

Comment: Yes, I tried your minimal example. It works until I get that For Each Next loop in there.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when ExportStatusSearch = 1 I get the error, but when ExportStatusSearch = 2, I don't and the code finishes successfully.